# Custom DEFLATE implementation to speed up PNG encoding

Tags: flash, png, compression, haxe, deflate

I'm optimizing a PNG encoder for use within Flash SWFs (but I'm writing it in [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)).

I've so far managed to speed things up a fair bit, mostly by using [speedy memory read/writes](http://webr3.org/blog/haxe/something-about-practical-usage-of-flash-memory-in-haxe/).

While profiling my code, I noticed that about 75% of the time is spent in a single call to Flash's built-in [compress()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#compress%28%29) method, which uses the zlib algorithm (which uses DEFLATE in turn).

I'm not too fussy about compression ratio, but *faster* compression would be awesome. So, I was wondering if it's worthwhile to try to implement zlib/DEFLATE myself. A little searching has turned up the zlib C-implementation source, but it's not exactly light reading (or easy to port!).

Are there any simple implementations of zlib/DEFLATE that I could use as a starting point? I'd rather not have to wade through the [two](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) [specs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt), especially since I don't know whether an implementation running in AVM2 could even perform as fast as the native Flash one in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up implementing deflate/zlib from scratch, and have just released it, and the PNG encoder that's built on top of it, on GitHub ([README](https://github.com/cameron314/PNGEncoder2/#readme)). I also wrote a blog post about the PNG encoder, with a [benchmark](http://moodycamel.com/blog/2011/a-better-png-encoder-for-flash#results) comparing it to other encoders.

The compression implementation is contained in [DeflateStream.hx](https://github.com/cameron314/PNGEncoder2/blob/master/DeflateStream.hx), and does manage to speed up the encoding process significantly (and allows it to be made completely asynchronous).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will be able to achieve better performances with a non-native deflate algorithm. You might be able to run it asynchronously, though, which could make a difference. If you want to port it, I think it would be best to find an AS3 or JavaScript implementation, like https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate . Good Luck!

Comment: it seems there is an haXe written Inflate algorithm here http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/source/browse/trunk/format/tools/InflateImpl.hx

Comment: Thanks Waneck, I'll take a look at those. The HaXe inflate is interesting, but I only need deflating ;-)

Comment: @Cameron Oh, got it : )  .There seems to have a port of zlib for as3 here http://code.google.com/p/as3zlib/ . I haven't looked too deeply into it, but it seems it implements the whole thing from scratch. It's probably going to perform worst, but then you could calculate a part of it each ENTER_FRAME so it doesn't hang the app. Cheers!

Comment: @Waneck: Ooh, that should come in handy. After reading the author's comment, I realized that Flash's `compress()` *isn't* using deflate, it's using zlib, which in turn uses deflate (and the PNG spec says that the compression should be zlib format). So, I still need to implement deflate, but I've been neglecting zlib ;-)

Comment: The `zlib` format is only a simple wrapper around the `deflate` format. Thus if you can deflate and are able to calculate the Adler32 checksum (which is quite easy), you have the zlib format.

Comment: @Waneck: +1, thanks! I finally finished my implementation, which I ended up doing from scratch, and it is comparable in performance to the native code Adobe uses (always with tradeoffs, of course, but mine was specifically intended for PNG data, which tends to be highly redundant). I do also support asynchronous encoding. See my answer more details.

Answer (score 1):

try to use [fzip](http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/) or [ascompress](http://code.google.com/p/ascompress/)

Comment: Thanks, but those both use Flash's built-in deflate()/compress() methods for the actual compression